# ASP.NET MVC Required DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I am building my first app with ASP.NET, and I am using Entity Framework.

I have two classes:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Empty Owner name")]
    [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage="Up to 10 chars")]
    [Display(Name="Owners name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Born { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Dog> dogs { get; set; }
}
public class Dog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Empty dog name")]
    [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage="Up to 10 chars")]
    [Display(Name="Dogs name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner owner { get; set; }
}
```

I can add owners to the database, but I cannot add dogs.
I am using a textbox and a listbox in the View like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Dog"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name);
    <br />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.owner.ID, new MvcApplication2.Models.GazdiKutyaDB().GetOwners());
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

I created a `GetOwners` method to add the existing owners to a listbox, and for the user, to select who is the owner of the dog.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetOwners()
{
    List<SelectListItem> g = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (Owner item in owners)
    {
         SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem();
         sli.Text = item.Name;
         sli.Value = item.ID.ToString();
         g.Add(sli);
    }
    return g;
}
```

I created a Controller for the Dogs. Here is my adding method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult New()
{            
     return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(Dog k)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          k.owner = (from x in db.owners
                      where x.ID == k.owner.ID
                      select x).FirstOrDefault();
          db.dogs.Add(k);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dog"); 
     }
     else
     {
          return View(k);
     }
}
```

I inserted breakpoints, and the reason why `ModelState.IsValid` is false, is that the owners name is empty: `[Required(ErrorMessage="Empty Owner name")]` I don't understand this, because I want to add a dog there.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add the ownerID to the class like so:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Empty dog name")]
    [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage="Up to 10 chars")]
    [Display(Name="Dogs name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ownerID { get; set; }
}
```

This is the easiest way to do it (in my opinion) when you are working with a database.

[Here is an excellent video tutorial, showing ways to get your models to work as expected in EF](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Entity-Framework-Tips-and-Tricks)